# Currency Formatter: respect locale preferences but move the currency code always to the right - simplify code

Tags: swift, currency, nsnumberformatter, currency-formatting, numberformatter

I need to format an `NSNumber` to be of the following format (examples):

`123,456.44 EUR`, `123.456,44 CHF`, `123'456'123,44 USD`.

In short, the locale rules should be respected, but the currency code should be always put to the right of the value.

How could I achieve such behavior from the `NumberFormatter`?
I've already managed to get the exactly result I want by using the following code:

```
        let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        let locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
        let grouping = locale.groupingSeparator ?? ""
        let decimal = locale.decimalSeparator ?? ""
        currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currencyISOCode
        currencyFormatter.locale = locale
        currencyFormatter.currencyCode = currencyCode // My Custom currency code passed from the context, e.g. CHF, EUR, NOK, SEK, USD
        currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        currencyFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

        let format = "#\(grouping)##0\(decimal)00 ¤¤" // Here I'm setting the exact format I want the string to be

        currencyFormatter.positiveFormat = format
        currencyFormatter.negativeFormat = "-" + format
```

However, I think, there might be a simpler solution. I tried using `positiveSuffix` and set it to `¤¤`, but the output string then is incorrect, e.g. `EUR 123,123.22 ¤¤`.

Could the code I'm using be simplified to achieve the same purpose?

Comment: If you want `.currencyISOCode` but currency always on the right, the simplest solution is not to let the formatter handle currency at all. Just use `decimal` and append the currency to the formatted text.

Comment: @Sulthan that's exactly how I solved this issue.